# How is an imported name resolved in Scala? (Spark / Zeppelin)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have a script running in a paragraph with the Spark interpreter in Zeppelin. It has an import and the name imported can be resolved from the global namespace and also from a function, but not from a method inside a class.

This runs well on my computer's installation of Scala (2.12) but it doesn't work in Zeppelin (Scala 2.11).

```
import java.util.Calendar

def myFun: String = {
    // this works
    return Calendar.getInstance.toString
}

class MyClass {
    def myFun(): String = {
      // this doesn't
      return Calendar.getInstance.toString

      // this works
      return java.util.Calendar.getInstance.toString
    }
}
```

The error message is like:

```
import java.util.Calendar
myFun: String
<console>:15: error: not found: value Calendar
                 return Calendar.getInstance.toString
```

What am I missing?

Comment: 1.11 ? are you sure not 2.11 ?

Comment: Yes, apologies for the typo!

Comment: Without having access to Spark/Zeppelin, I would speculate that this is a bug in how that system interprets _Scala_ scripts. The `import` statement should bring `java.util.Calendar` into scope as just `Calendar`; _every_ version of _Scala_ should honor that!

Comment: Which version of zeppelin do you use ? I don't see this issue in master branch.

Comment: @zjffdu I have this issue running 0.8.0

Comment: Apparently I have Version 0.7.3  (in the "About Zeppelin" section)

Answer (score 0):

In 0.8.0 Zeppelin has introduced a new SparkInterpreter I suppose due to which the global imports don't work and the imports have to be scoped within a wrapper.

As a workaround, the property zeppelin.spark.useNew can be set to the value "false". This disables the sparks new interpreter.